# Creating a relationship in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm new to laravel and I'm not really understanding how relationships work using it. I think I'm just having an "off" day as I'm struggling to do something relatively simple.

I have 2 tables. *items* and *inventory*

Each entry within the *inventory* table has a column labeled *itemid* and *userid*.

So for example, this could be the table *inventory* with its entries -

```
  id | userid | itemid  | ...
+-----------------------------------
| 1  |   1    |    1    | ...
| 2  |   1    |    4    | ...
| 3  |   1    |    6    | ...
| 4  |   2    |    1    | ...
```

(there are more columns but these are just the columns that link everything together)

Basically, what I'm trying to do is get all of the items that a user has. My normal method would just be using a JOIN query but I'm not really sure how it works in Laravel.

I have 2 very simple models just to retrieve the data from each table

Inventory.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Inventory extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'inventory';
}
```

Item.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Item extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'items';
}
```

How can I get the item data for each entry within the inventory table? I've tried defining relationships and such using the eloquent documentation but I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: In this case `inventory` is a pivot table. And relationships should be defined as many-to-many between User and Item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you have a `many-to-many` relationship between `User` and `Item`, so there's no need to use `Inventory` as a model, cause `inventory` table is just a pivot table.

Your models can look like:

```
class User extends Model
{

    public function inventory_items()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            'Item',                             // joined model
            'inventory',                        // pivot table name
            'userid',                           // column name in pivot table
            'itemid'                            // column name in pivot table
        );
    }
}
```

Items of user you can get with

```
$user = User::find($user_id);
$items = $user->inventory_items()->get();
```

Same technique can be applied to `Item` model.

**Update**: for retrieving additional pivot table colums - update your `inventory_items()` as:

```
public function inventory_items()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        'Item',                             // joined model
        'inventory',                        // pivot table name
        'userid',                           // column name in pivot table
        'itemid'                            // column name in pivot table
    )->withPivot('column_1', 'column_2')
}
```

Comment: Great! However, the inventory table also has a column named "equipped". How would I access this column using this method?

Comment: Tremendous! Works a treat! Thanks!